# Can I use the Pinterest script, and disable the pin it button from it on my photos?

Tags: javascript, html, widget, pinterest

I would like to be able to use the Pinterest profile widget on my Tumblr so my visitors can get a quick look at what I post on Pinterest without actually having to visit my full profile directly. However, the script needed to add the widget to my site adds the grey and red "Pin It" button to each of my photos, in place of the CSS styled button I made myself, and hides my custom button [which works as any other link].

Is there any way I can use the Pinterest widget, without having Pinterest's "Pin It" button show up on my photo posts, and use my CSS styled button instead? I highly prefer to use my custom button and hide the default as it suites my theme better.

I am using the following meta tag to disable the "Pin It" button created by the browser plugin.

`<meta name="pinterest" content="nopin" />`

I know the codes needed for widgets are pretty straight forward as they come directly from Pinterest, but here is the script needed to run the profile widget if you need it.

`<script async defer src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>`

And here is my personal widget I'd like to add to my site as well.

`<a data-pin-do="embedUser" data-pin-board-width="220" data-pin-scale-height="275" data-pin-scale-width="80" href="http://www.pinterest.com/meowingatmoons/"></a>`

Any help at being able to use this without having to use the default Pin button [if possible] would be great! I know that you can upload your own image to use as a pin button, but I highly prefer to use my CSS styled button I created as I want it to blend with the other links on my posts.

Comment: seems you're using pinit - is that the only API pinterest offer? https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/sdks/js/

Comment: I've looked through the links on that page, and searched google for an alternative.. and I can't seem to find anything. It may be possible to create one from what I see with javascript, although I'm not entirely sure. However, I don't really know how to write javascript myself.

Comment: it just seems odd to use the pinit API, and want to remove the "Pin It" functionality

Comment: I can understand what you're saying there. It's not so much wanting to remove the functionality all-together. It's more that I'd prefer to show the custom button I've made, rather than the "Pin It" button from that API. I wanted all my buttons on my posts to look consistent.. so I made the pin it function as a custom button like this `<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url={Permalink}&media={PhotoURL-250}" title="Save To Pinterest" target="blank"  class="pin-it-button" count-layout="horizontal" ><div id="permabutton">Pin It</div></a>`

Comment: Well I'm not sure what I did, but I got it to work the way I want it to. My custom CSS styled button is showing with the API on my theme, rather than the API's default button. It could just be that the default pin button shows when developer tools are open, but then uses styled button once they are all closed.

Comment: could be a caching issue too